# How to get tagged posts for a specific blog using Tumblr API V2?

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

I have read the Tumblr API V2 documentation and understand that I can use the `/posts` method with the **tag** parameter to get posts from a specific blog with a specific tag, but the response I get doesn't contain any posts, just the total count.

This is true for any blog and tag combination I try. I am using javascript (not the official client) but the result is the same even when I use the Tumblr API Console or type a request directly into the browser URL.

Example request:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/washingtonpost.tumblr.com/posts/text?tag=culture&api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4
```

Response:

```
{"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},"response":{"blog":{"title":"The Washington Post","name":"washingtonpost","posts":2647,"url":"http:\/\/washingtonpost.tumblr.com\/","updated":1412647225,"description":"Things you should see and know, from civil rights to Senate races to sports to book reviews. Curated by Julia Carpenter.","is_nsfw":false,"ask":true,"ask_page_title":"Ask away!","ask_anon":true,"share_likes":false},"posts":[],"total_posts":7}}
```

The `response.total_posts` count is accurate, but why is the `response.posts` array empty? How could I use this response to get the actual posts?

Edit:

As of today there are 7 posts on the Washington Post blog tagged "culture". There is 1 text post, 3 quote posts and 3 photo posts.

[This request returns all 3 photo posts](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/washingtonpost.tumblr.com/posts/photo?tag=culture&api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4).

[This request returns all 3 quote posts](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/washingtonpost.tumblr.com/posts/quote?tag=culture&api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4).

[So why does this request not return the 1 text post?](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/washingtonpost.tumblr.com/posts/text?tag=culture&api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4)

Comment: After further research this would appear to be a bug in the Tumblr API when the type is set to "text". This example from the API documentation works as expected: http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/pitchersandpoets.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&tag=new+york+yankees but change the type from "photo" to "text" and you get the empty posts array: http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/pitchersandpoets.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&tag=new+york+yankees

Comment: So apparently the total_posts count is for all posts with the specified tag *of any type*, not just the type being requested. So it is possible to get no posts for the requested type when total_posts > 0, however, the problem does still exist but my example in the previous comment is wrong because there are no text posts with that tag anyway.

Comment: Seems like a bug. I would submit the issue to Tumblr.

Comment: I've emailed Tumblr and signed up for the Google group (awaiting approval) but wanted to post here in case someone had come across this before. Can't see a workaround though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in the Tumblr API. Hopefully a fix will be available shortly.

[Bug report on Tumblr Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tumblr-api/WMCNWES07TY)